# Can I make the BT module disconnect with a BT module and connect with another in the code?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, wireless, hc-05

I am working on a project that requires a connection between two BT modules (HC-05) and a mobile phone. Later on, I encountered a problem: I can't connect two BT modules to one at the same time, So I thought about the possibility of ending a connection and starting the other one when needed. If that was possible, how can I do that in an arduino code?

One of the BT modules is a master which means it can't connect to the phone and it has to be a master because it must be connected to the other slave BT module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send `AT+ROLE=1` to BT module to set module into master role.
To set module back to slave mode, send `AT+ROLE=0`

Also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i-6cz4KHXE), you have source code in the description. It will help you understand how to do it.

Comment: But that requires reversing the rx-tx connection to enter the AT mode from the connection being used to send and receive data, which as far as I know can't be done during the code execution as the pins setup is being configured once at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Can you share your code? Serial comm(RX TX) is two way communication

Comment: I haven't written a code yet.

Comment: Try with this command. You can't know without the  code

Comment: As I knew recently that the BT connection is a point to point connection which means that can't connect the two BT modules and the mobile in one network at the same time.

Comment: That's true, only one device can be connected to one BT module. It's normall.

Comment: I have tried many time to enter the AT command mode connecting the tx with the rx and vice versa but it didn't work. Strange characters were appearing on the serial monitor. It didn't work till I connected the rx with the rx and the tx with the tx.

Comment: TX from BT module goes into RX pin from Arduino and vice versa. That's the way you talk with BT module.

Comment: So I decided to use the slave module to communicate between the masters in different times (connects with one and disconnects with the other). How can I make the BT module do that (to disconnect with the current BT module and wait for connection with another known module)?

Comment: To connect the BT module to the arduino for communication Rx to TX and TX to RX is used. But to enter the AT mode I had to connect the RX to the RX and the TX with the TX and it worked.

Comment: Send proper command to BT module. Here's [link](https://www.teachmemicro.com/hc-05-bluetooth-command-list/) with list of all commands for HC-05 BT module. **Anwser is edited**

Comment: @SilvioCro, the trick with connecting RX to RX, TX to TX is that then the USB chip is connected RX to TX to module and you can talk to module from the Serial Monitor. The main MCU must have a sketch without Serial.begin() (empty sketch or Blink)